# Node Sequelize with Mysql order by, need null values to be last

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using the node module Sequelize for my service, which has a mysql backend. I need to retrieve records sorted by ascending closing date (value stored as unix timestamp). But the closing date can be null, and I need for records with null closing date to be last.

This query works in mysql:
select * from my_table order by -closing_date DESC;

However, I can't seem to configure Sequelize to do this.

Looking into the Sequelize library, I find that there is support for an ORDER BY closing_date ASC NULLS LAST. But as far as I can tell, this syntax is not supported by mysql. Only mssql.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

In mysql, another way to do the above query is like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY ISNULL(closing_date), closing_date ASC
```

This can be done in sequelize like this:

```
records.findAll({
    order: [
        sequelize.fn('isnull', sequelize.col('closing_date')),
        ['closing_date', 'ASC']
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the "order" function. Since you're using nodejs module you can try something like this :

```
records.findAll({
  order: [
    sequelize.fn('max', sequelize.col('date')),
  ]
})
```

Comment: From what I understand, 'max' will just return a single row, which is not what I need. What I need a list of my items sorted by increasing closing_date, where the items that have a null closing_date come after the items that have a closing date.